# how to mock a class with metaclass inheritance decorator wrapt_timeout_decorator

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

In this test it only simulates the call to a class method that in turn calls another class, and both inherit a `metaclass` that uses the `wrapt_timeout_decorator` library, so that all methods of a class are decorated with this wrapper, for control of waiting times.However, when doing this test it fails, because `call_count` is 0. However, when "eliminating" the inheritance of the `FirstService` class the test works, does anyone know what having the `metaclass` influences inheritance? Since when you remove it the test works correctly.

```
from wrapt_timeout_decorator import timeout
import inspect
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

class TimeoutManager(type):
    """
    A metaclass used to wrap all methods of external classes with a timeout decorator
    for controlling timeouts in the backend.

    Usage:
    class YourClass(metaclass=TimeoutManager):
        ...
    """

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        """
        Overrides the creation of a new class.

        Args:
        - name (str): The name of the class.
        - bases (tuple): The base classes of the class.
        - dct (dict): The class dictionary.

        Returns:
        - type: The new class.
        """

        for key, value in dct.items():
            # Check if method is not a magic method
            if callable(value) and not key.startswith("__"):
                # Check if method has the @timeout decorator
                validation: bool = cls.has_timeout_decorator(value)
                if not validation:
                    dct[key] = cls.default_timeout_wrapper()(value)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    @classmethod
    def default_timeout_wrapper(cls) -> callable:
        """
        Returns a default timeout wrapper.

        Returns:
        - callable: Timeout wrapper function.
        """
        return timeout(
            45,
            use_signals=False,
            timeout_exception=TimeoutError,
            exception_message="Tiempo de espera agotado , favor intente nuevamente.",
        )

    @classmethod
    def has_timeout_decorator(cls, method: callable) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if a method has the @timeout decorator.

        Args:
        - method (callable): The method to check.

        Returns:
        - bool: True if the @timeout decorator is present, False otherwise.
        """
        decorators_method: list = cls.get_decorators(method)
        if len(decorators_method) > 0:
            if "timeout" in decorators_method:
                return True
        return False

    @classmethod
    def get_decorators(cls, method: callable) -> list:
        """
        Extracts decorators from the source code of a method.

        Args:
        - method (callable): The method to extract decorators from.

        Returns:
        - list: List of decorator names.
        """
        decorators: list = []
        source_lines, _ = inspect.getsourcelines(method)
        source_lines: list = source_lines
        for line in source_lines:
            stripped_line: str = line.strip()
            if stripped_line.startswith("@"):
                decorator_name: list = stripped_line.split("(")[0][1:]
                decorators.append(decorator_name)
        return decorators




class FirstService(metaclass=TimeoutManager):
    """Service class for performing inference operations."""

    @classmethod
    def persist_metadata(resource_info) :
        """Process the query and generate a response.

        Args:
            interaction (InteractionModel): The user's interaction

        Returns:
            PathResponse: Processed response object.
        """
       
        return resource_info
    
    @classmethod
    def get_sample_sql(setup_conversation) :
        return setup_conversation

# Clase base con métodos
class SecondService(metaclass=TimeoutManager):
    @staticmethod
    def setup_chat(setup_conversation):
        metadata_response: dict = FirstService().persist_metadata(
            setup_conversation
        )
        sql_code_sample: str = FirstService().get_sample_sql(setup_conversation)
        response: dict = {
            "metadata": metadata_response,
            "sql_code_sample": sql_code_sample,
        }
        return response


class TestBaseServices:

    def test_setup_conversation_chat(
        self
    ):
        mock_setup_conversation_chat = "HELLO"
        metadata_mock_response: dict = {"response": "value", "is_saved_succes": True}
        sql_code_sample_mock: str = "SELECT * FROM table;"

        with patch.object(
            FirstService, "persist_metadata", return_value=metadata_mock_response
        ) as mock_persist:
            with patch.object(
                FirstService, "get_sample_sql", return_value=sql_code_sample_mock
            ) as mock_get_sql:
                response = SecondService.setup_chat(
                    mock_setup_conversation_chat
                )

                print("Persist Metadata Calls:", mock_persist.call_count)
                print("Get Sample SQL Calls:", mock_get_sql.call_count)

                mock_persist.assert_called_once_with(mock_setup_conversation_chat)
                mock_get_sql.assert_called_once_with(mock_setup_conversation_chat)

                assert "metadata" in response and "sql_code_sample" in response
                assert response["metadata"] == metadata_mock_response
                assert response["sql_code_sample"] == sql_code_sample_mock

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Because by removing class SecondService(metaclass=TimeoutManager) and leaving only class SecondService, that is, removing the inheritance of the metaclass in SecondService, does the test work? How does metaclass inheritance affect the test's failure?